# Converting String to series of characters and adding value - not working

Tags: javascript

I'm pretty new to JavaScript. I've written a function, which should take a String submitted to a form, and convert into array of chars, which then assigns each char a monetary value, and then returns the total of these values. The String may contain spaces, which should be given the value of zero. The following doesn't work though. I'm expecting it to display "Total number is: " plus the total on my html page. This function is called when information is entered into a text field, and a submit button hit. Instead, it just redirects to the page I have set under the action attribute in my  tag.

Any pointers?

```
function validate() {

var total = 0;

var x = document.forms["myForm"]["UserInfo"].value;

var chars = x.toLowerCase().split('');

var alphabet = [" ",   "a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"];

 for (i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) { 
    //var letterValue = alphabet.indexOf(splitted_string[i])+1;
    var characterPosition = alphabet.indexOf(chars[i]);

    total += characterPosition;
 }

    return total;

    document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "Total number is: " + total;  

}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific when you say that the code doesn't work - what output are you getting? What are you expecting or wanting?

Comment: I'll update Daniel

Comment: You are `return`ing before affecting the DOM.

Comment: Also, it looks like your `return` statement is above the line where you set an element's `innerHTML` with the answer.

Comment: Ah yes!! So simple!! Thank you so much both!!

Comment: Yes, your problem is returning before writing to the dom. Your function is working: https://jsfiddle.net/mrlew/wreozy10/1/ . And you don't need to split the string, just use `string[position]`. Check the fiddle.

Comment: Even after you fix the return placement, it's still going to redirect to the action URL. You have to `return false` to stop the form submission (assuming the form has `onsubmit="return validate()"`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `return` statement is above the line where you set an element's `innerHTML` with the answer. So, that statement is not getting executed.

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me

```
validate()
function validate() {

  var total = 0;

  var x = 'a sd'//document.forms["myForm"]["UserInfo"].value;

  var chars = x.toLowerCase().split('');

  var alphabet = [" ",   "a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"];

  for (i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
    //var letterValue = alphabet.indexOf(splitted_string[i])+1;
    var characterPosition = alphabet.indexOf(chars[i]);
    console.log(characterPosition);
    total += characterPosition;
  }
  console.log('total: ' + total)
  return total;

  document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "Total number is: " + total;

}
```

Here my output

1

0

19

4

total: 24

My hunch is that your return statement is before your

```
`document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "Total number is: " + total;`
```

so it doesn't get executed